# Многомерный ассоциативный массив в JAVA

Tags: java

Привет.

Имеется код:

```
  Map<String, List<String>> HashMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> string_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        string_list.add("Whysss?");
        string_list.add("a1_q");
        string_list.add("a2_q");

        HashMap.put("ONE", string_list);

        string_list.add("Whysss?_2");
        string_list.add("a1_q_2");
        string_list.add("a2_q_2");

        HashMap.put("TWO", string_list);

        System.out.println(HashMap.get("ONE"));
        System.out.println(HashMap.get("TWO"));

Результат:

[Whysss?, a1_q, a2_q, Whysss?_2, a1_q_2, a2_q_2]
[Whysss?, a1_q, a2_q, Whysss?_2, a1_q_2, a2_q_2]
```

Вопрос в том, что и ключ "ONE" и ключ "TWO" возвращают, один и тот же блок,  а мне надо,
чтобы "ONE" возвращал [Whysss?, a1_q, a2_q], a "TWO" [Whysss?_2, a1_q_2, a2_q_2].

Может не использовать HashMap? Есть ли в ЯВА какая нибудь более удобная реализация многомерного ассоциативного массива?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в мапе храняться пары строка, ссылка. Можете проверить, добавив в переменную `string_list` еще элементов, и повторно выполнив `Map.get()`

Вот как вариант:

```
HashMap.put("ONE", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("el1", "el2")));

HashMap.put("TWO", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("el3", "el4")));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. То что нужно. Коротко и ясно. И правда ведь, ссылку указываю... что-то с утра  не так все идет, элементарного уже не замечаю :)

Answer (score 3):

А вы попробуйте разные элементы в `HashMap` засунуть. А то и в первом и во втором случае, вы кладете в катру один и тот же список. Конечно же, тогда и в первом и во втором ключе (ONE, TWO), будет одно и то же.

Comment: Спасибо. :) С утра туплю что-то.